# Emulate two android devices connected over a WiFi network?

Tags: android

I want to know if it's possible to use two emulator instances and simulate that are connected to the same network over wifi.

Is it possible with the default emulator or any other pay emulator ? Or should I just buy two devices ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run two android emulator instances. The emulators will be using your native computer's network interface for connectivity and will be able to talk to each other.